# Compare two same databases and get missing or not actual data in tables

Tags: compare, firebird, firebird2.5

I have very specific problem with export Firebird database to another system. Full export takes very long time. My plan is a create copy of database and start with export to new system. Users can continue to write and change data to an uncopied database.

My problem is how to solve missing or updated data in copied database. Is possible to compare those databases and get third database only with new or updated data? After compare missing or updated data, import them to new system. Is there any tool, or command to achieve this?

Comment: online databse replication is very complex topic, intimately coupled with application logic and data structure. If what you need is one time move to an empty tabula rasa system and that users would never work with both systems at once, you may try to abuse old "shadow database" functionality or to use newer "incremental backup" (nbackup) one.

Comment: If users are working with database - you are in a dead end: your hare will never catch up with the turtle. Better find quicker way for export (such as mentioned nbackup or file copy).